# How to build the cristmas tree?

Tags: happy-street

How do I build the christmas tree on happy street. It does not show in either the forest crafts or the workshop crafts?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Happy Street Wiki, the [Christmas Tree](http://happystreet.wikia.com/wiki/Christmas_Tree) is available:

> In Themes shop during the Christmas season.